# Drawing random data from a given two dimensional distribution function

Tags: numpy, scipy, probability, static-methods, probability-theory

I have a theoretical distribution and I want to randomly sample in 2D space for the following distribution :

```
def p(z,m):
    E = { 'ft':0.55, 'alpha': 2.99, 'z0':0.191, 'km':0.089, 'kt':0.25 }
    S = { 'ft':0.39, 'alpha': 2.15, 'z0':0.121, 'km':0.093, 'kt':-0.175 }
    I={ 'ft':0.06, 'alpha': 1.77, 'z0':0.045, 'km':0.096, 'kt':0.0 }
    Evalue=E['ft']*np.exp(-1*E['kt']*(m-20))*z**E['alpha']*np.exp(-1*(z/(E['z0']+E['km']*(m-20)))**E['alpha'])
    Svalue=S['ft']*np.exp(-1*S['kt']*(m-20))*z**S['alpha']*np.exp(-1*(z/(S['z0']+S['km']*(m-20)))**S['alpha'])
    Ivalue=I['ft']*np.exp(-1*I['kt']*(m-20))*z**I['alpha']*np.exp(-1*(z/(I['z0']+I['km']*(m-20)))**I['alpha'])
    value=Evalue+Svalue+Ivalue
    return value
```

**Update**:
I figured out that inverse transform sampling is the appropriate approach to sample data from a probability distribution. 
How could I  program this method in python for 2D data or is there any library that I can use?

Comment: The simplest thing, if you don't have big speed constrains, is to use the rejection method.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Markov chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) methods. Basically you jump around the space of (z, m) points. From wherever you are, you always accept a jump that increases p(z, m). You accept a jump which decreases p(z, m) with some probability. There is a Python library PyMC to carry out that process.

Comment: What about something like `inverse transform sampling` in 2D but the problem is how to make an inverse `CDF` for a complicated 2D distribution.

Comment: No, inverse transform sampling isn't directly applicable in more than 1 dimension. You could construct p(m | z) and p(z) and sample first from p(z) and then p(m | z) by the inverse transform method, but that's an unnecessary complication. Better to attack the problem directly via MCMC.

Comment: Or just code the [Metropolis-Hastings algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm), which is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to randomly sample a value from p(z,m), then a simple way to implement this would be to use the 'random' module in python. I show the idea using numpy's version of random:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def p(z,m):
    E = { 'ft':0.55, 'alpha': 2.99, 'z0':0.191, 'km':0.089, 'kt':0.25 }
    S = { 'ft':0.39, 'alpha': 2.15, 'z0':0.121, 'km':0.093, 'kt':-0.175 }
    I={ 'ft':0.06, 'alpha': 1.77, 'z0':0.045, 'km':0.096, 'kt':0.0 }
    Evalue=E['ft']*np.exp(-1*E['kt']*(m-20))*z**E['alpha']*np.exp(-1*(z/(E['z0']+E['km']*(m-20)))**E['alpha'])
    Svalue=S['ft']*np.exp(-1*S['kt']*(m-20))*z**S['alpha']*np.exp(-1*(z/(S['z0']+S['km']*(m-20)))**S['alpha'])
    Ivalue=I['ft']*np.exp(-1*I['kt']*(m-20))*z**I['alpha']*np.exp(-1*(z/(I['z0']+I['km']*(m-20)))**I['alpha'])
    value=Evalue+Svalue+Ivalue
    return value

# Define the number of iterations you want for each variable    
num_iter_m = 50
num_iter_z = 50

# I then set rand_m to go from 20 to 30, as your function fails for <20
rand_m = (np.random.random(num_iter_m)*10)+20

# z goes from the range 0 - 1
rand_z = (np.random.random(num_iter_z))

# Note, I am sampling from a uniform distribution for m and z. You can use more complicated functions, i.e., Gaussian/Normal shapes or even user defined.

rand_p = np.zeros((len(rand_z), len(rand_m)))

# Fill a grid with the random p(z,m) values
for i in range(len(rand_z)):
  for j in range(len(rand_m)):
    rand_p[i][j] = p(rand_z[i], rand_m[j])

# Plot
fig = plt.figure(0)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.scatter(rand_z, rand_m)
ax1.set_xlabel("z")
ax1.set_ylabel("m")

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
cf = ax2.contourf(rand_z, rand_m, rand_p)
ax2.set_xlabel("z")
ax2.set_ylabel("m")

colbar = plt.colorbar(cf)
colbar.set_label("p(z,m)")

plt.show()
```

[image: sample image]

A specific module to use to it in a more sophisticated way would be, e.g., PyMC (
https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc) or emcee (http://dan.iel.fm/emcee/current/).

If you wanted to sample z and m weighted by the 2D function p(z,m) this is a little more complicated.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a solution to the problem posed by OP. "If you wanted to sample z and m weighted by the 2D function p(z,m)" -- I'm pretty sure that's what he wants.